# Why does my live stream camera lag severely with OpenCV+Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Using Visual Studio 2019, I successfully built OpenCV library `WITH_QT` enabled.
Live streaming with my webcam lags severely. Here is the code.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if (!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat frame;
    const string name = "frame";
    namedWindow(name,WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL);

    while (true)
    {
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        imshow(name, frame);
        if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    cap.release();
}
```

## Question

What causes the lag?

Note: Several weeks ago when I used OpenCV without Qt and using my old computer (before [got burnt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xm61.jpg)), the live stream did not lag.

Comment: What do you mean by "severely" lagging? What frame rate do you get?

Comment: @user1810087: I cannot measure the frame rate exactly, but it is about 1/3-1/4 fps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I got the solution but I don't know the reason.
I unplug the webcam from the USB 3.0 and plug to USB 2.0. Now it runs smoothly. 
If you think this question and answer must be deleted, I will do.